# How to load the latest version of bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I saw someone referencing:

> ```
> http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/1.4.0/bootstrap.min.css
> ```

But what I'd like to do is load "the latest" of version 1, similar to how Google cdn includes all the versions of a library along with "the latest" one.

Q: Is there something that I can load like:

> http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/1/bootstrap.min.css

To get the latest version 1 of twitter bootstrap?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK there isn't a pre-compiled version of the bootstrap css available on github, but I suppose you could reference http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/assets/css/bootstrap.css, which is the one used by their site (but obviously this is not guaranteed to work indefinitely)

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is a reason to do so.
You always should test a new version to make sure it doesn't break your current application.

Comment: You're right!  Actually, I've gotten burned by a jQuery update before.  But during development, I always want the latest version.